# Group by after a inner joining twice - Sorting by ascending

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Practising SQL and wanted to sort results of my query - the raw query runs fine however when grouped by it fails to run.

Using SSMS '18 - using the `AdventureWorks` database.

```
SELECT 
    pp.BusinessEntityID,
    pp.FirstName,
    pp.MiddleName,
    pp.LastName,
    ppw.PasswordHash,
    ppw.PasswordSalt,
    pph.PhoneNumber
FROM
    Person.Person AS pp
INNER JOIN
    Person.Password AS ppw ON pp.BusinessEntityID = ppw.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN
    Person.PersonPhone AS pph ON pp.BusinessEntityID = pph.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY 
    pp.BusinessEntityID ASC, pp.FirstName, pp.MiddleName, pp.LastName, 
    ppw.PasswordHash, ppw.PasswordSalt, pph.PhoneNumber;
```

Result in an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ASC'.

The code will run if the ASC keyword is removed and group by `BusinessEntityID` descending. Am I missing some theory here?

Comment: You can use ASC in the ORDER BY clause, not in GROUP BY.

Comment: SQL 101: `asc` and `desc` are only meaningful (and therefor are only allowed) in the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be order by not group by

```
SELECT 
 pp.BusinessEntityID,
 pp.FirstName,
 pp.MiddleName,
 pp.LastName,
 ppw.PasswordHash,
 ppw.PasswordSalt,
 pph.PhoneNumber
FROM
Person.Person as pp
    inner join Person.Password as ppw on  pp.BusinessEntityID=ppw.BusinessEntityID
    inner join Person.PersonPhone as pph on pp.BusinessEntityID=pph.BusinessEntityID
order by  pp.BusinessEntityID ASC, pp.FirstName, pp.MiddleName, pp.LastName, ppw.PasswordHash, ppw.PasswordSalt, pph.PhoneNumber;
```

but if you want to use group by then it will be

```
SELECT 
     pp.BusinessEntityID,
     pp.FirstName,
     pp.MiddleName,
     pp.LastName,
     ppw.PasswordHash,
     ppw.PasswordSalt,
     pph.PhoneNumber
    FROM
    Person.Person as pp
        inner join Person.Password as ppw on  pp.BusinessEntityID=ppw.BusinessEntityID
        inner join Person.PersonPhone as pph on pp.BusinessEntityID=pph.BusinessEntityID
    group  by  pp.BusinessEntityID , pp.FirstName, pp.MiddleName, pp.LastName, ppw.PasswordHash, ppw.PasswordSalt, pph.PhoneNumber;
```

but distinct is better if no aggregation is there  , group by is for aggregation